# How to make TextView chars the same size?

Tags: java, android, layout, fonts, textview

I need to show in TextView chars with the same size in pixels, can it be done using a custom font or something like that?

Take for example the char ';' takes 8 pixels in width and a space ' ' takes 7 pixels in width, how can i make those the same size?

Comment: Using a mono-spaced font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<TextView
    android:typeface="monospace"
    ...
    />
```

in your TextView